# Drupal 8 Configuration file based, missing fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

We currently developing a new Drupal 8 website and having problems with missing fields. We use the file configuration instead of database configuration because of the deployment process and stand-alone develop environments of our developers.

After we added some fields by developer 1, they shown up in the .yml config files and are visible in the entities by developer 2 but not in the autocomplete to add fields when we create a view. We run the entity update commands, database update etc.
They are also missing via Reports > Field List. The fields only show up correct on the database on which they are created in de admin.

Do you have any ideas why they are missing?
It seems to be a problem in the key_value table but how can we update or rebuild that table?